# Redirection of output in shell script lines in Makefiles

Tags: shell, makefile

I'm trying to figure out what one specific line in a makefile is doing:

```
foo: smth_foo_depends_on
    ...
    @echo $< | bar >> $@
    ...
```

In particular I'd like to know:

- why do we write `@` before `echo`;
- what does `$<` mean;
- why do we output something in `$@` which, as far as I know, is the list of arguments given to the script? Why do we modify it?

Thanks!

Comment: learn all from the doc: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html#Top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Why do we write `@` before `echo`?*

[Source](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Echoing.html): It is done to suppress the *echoing* for one specific line in the recipe.

> *What does `$<` mean?*

[Source](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html): `$<` is the name of the first prerequisite (i.e. `smth_foo_depends_on`)

> *Why do we output something in `$@` which, as far as I know, is the list of arguments given to the script? Why do we modify it?*

[Source](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html): In makefile language, `$@` is the name of the current target (i.e. `foo`). Do not confuse it with the shell list of positional parameters. The recipe line `echo $< | bar >> $@` is expanded to:

```
echo smth_foo_depends_on | bar >> foo
```